# Homogeneous Differential Equation y'=1/(y-x)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have been given the following ODE:
$$y'=\frac{1}{y-x}$$

I verify that it is homogeneous by doing:
$$y'=\frac{1}{\lambda y-\lambda x}$$
$$y'= \frac{1}{\lambda (y-x)}$$
$$y'=\lambda ^{-1} \frac{1}{y-x} $$

Therefore, it is a homogenous equation of degree -1.

At this point, I would do the following substitution: $y=ux$, $y'=u'x+u$.

$$u'x+u=\frac{1}{ux-x}$$
$$u'x+u=\frac{1}{x(u-1)}$$
$$u'x=\frac{1}{x(u-1)}-u$$
$$u'x=\frac{1-ux(u-1)}{x(u-1)}$$
$$u'=\frac{1-ux(u-1)}{x^2(u-1)}$$

I do not know how to continue from here as in all the homogeneous ODE I have seen so far, I was able to separate $x$ and $u(x)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Take the reciprocal of both sides, then it becomes a linear differential equation with dependent variable y. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @IshraaqParvez Do you mean the following? $\frac{1}{y'}-y+x=0$. I can't separate the variables here either and I only know how to solve linear differential equations when they can be put as $y'+f(x)y+g(x)=0$ What I should do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit inexperienced at this matter, but here goes my idea:

This doesn't look like an homogeneous equation since:
\begin{equation*}
f(x,y) \neq f(\lambda x,\lambda y)
\end{equation*}
So my suggestion is the following:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{y-x} \Leftrightarrow \frac{dx}{dy} = y-x \Leftrightarrow \frac{dx}{dy} = (-1)x+y
\end{equation*}

Which is now a linear equation, solvable with easier methods.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to solve it by making $x$ the dependent variable.